# matplotlib dates scaling x axis with rules

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I found some examples that I tweaked to make my x-axis what I desire for one case only.

```
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

def my_format_function(x, pos=None):
    x = dates.num2date(x)
    if pos == 0:
        fmt = '%H:%M\n%d-%b-%Y'
    else:
        fmt = '%H:%M'
    label = x.strftime(fmt)
    return label

# make up some data
x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(250)]
y = [i+random.gauss(0,1) for i,_ in enumerate(x)]

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), facecolor='white', edgecolor='black')
plt.plot(x,y)

x_axis = plt.gca().get_xaxis()

x_axis.set_major_locator(dates.HourLocator())
x_axis.set_major_formatter(dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(my_format_function))

x_axis.set_minor_locator(dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(15,60,15)))
x_axis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter(':%M'))

x_axis.set_tick_params(which='major', labelsize=10)
x_axis.set_tick_params(which='minor', pad=4, labelsize=8, labelcolor='#333333')

plt.grid(which = 'minor', alpha = 0.4)
plt.grid(which = 'major', alpha = 0.9)

plt.show()
```

[Example plot for x_axis formatting datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWkQO.png)

I recently saw some examples, but I couldn't follow along, where AutoDateFormatter was used with some rules to accommodate different amounts of time, etc.  I could use some help.  Here are the rules I was looking to start out with and see where it takes me.

[Example x_axis rules for formatting datetime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Us87y.png)

UPDATE:
After some serious digging, I was able to achieve what I wanted, but I feel it is horribly over coded.  I will be able to push the def's into a seperate file to clean up.  I am open to some serious suggestions to trim and clean.  I still need to capture methods for times <1 second along with times >1day.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Oct 01 15:31:31 2016

@author: Frank
"""

import numpy as np
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as dates

def formatterMinorMicroSeconds(x,pos=None):
    x = dates.num2date(x)
    label = x.strftime('%S.')+str(int(x.microsecond/1000))+'s'
    return label

def formatterMajorSeconds(x, pos=None):
    x = dates.num2date(x)
    if (non_crossing_minute==True and pos == 0) or (non_crossing_minute ==False and x.second == 0):
        fmt = '\n%H:%M:%S\n%d-%b-%Y'
    else:
        fmt = ''
    label = x.strftime(fmt)
    return label

def formatterMajorMinutes(x, pos=None):
    x = dates.num2date(x)
    if (non_crossing_hour==True and pos == 0) or (non_crossing_hour == False and x.minute == 0):
        fmt = '\n%H:%M\n%d-%b-%Y'
    else:
        fmt = '\n%H:%M'
    label = x.strftime(fmt)
    return label
    datetime.datetime.strftime()

def formatterMajorHours(x, pos=None):
    x = dates.num2date(x)
    if (non_crossing_day==True and pos == 0) or (non_crossing_day == False and x.hour == 0):
        fmt = '\n%H:%M\n%d-%b-%Y'
    else:
        fmt = '\n%H:%M'
    label = x.strftime(fmt)
    return label
    datetime.datetime.strftime()

def dynamicDateLocator(x):
    global non_crossing_minute, non_crossing_hour, non_crossing_day

    #establish the time boundaries
    start_time = x.min()
    stop_time = x.max()
    # establish time delta for plot duration hours, seconds, microseconds
    time_delta = stop_time - start_time


    if time_delta.days == 0:
        # first determine if the plot crosses from one minute to the next
        if time_delta.seconds + start_time.second < 60:
            non_crossing_minute = True
        else:
            non_crossing_minute = False
        if time_delta.seconds/60 + start_time.minute < 60:
            non_crossing_hour = True
        else:
            non_crossing_hour = False
        if time_delta.seconds/3600 + start_time.hour < 24:
            non_crossing_day = True
        else:
            non_crossing_day = False    

        # format major and minor scaling based on how large the time scale is
        if time_delta.seconds < 2:     # 2 seconds
            return dates.SecondLocator(bysecond=range(0,60,1)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorSeconds), \
                   dates.MicrosecondLocator(interval=200000),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMinorMicroSeconds)
        elif time_delta.seconds < 30:  # 30 seconds  
            return dates.SecondLocator(bysecond=range(0,60,5)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorSeconds), \
                   dates.MicrosecondLocator(interval=1000000),dates.DateFormatter('%Ss')
        elif time_delta.seconds < 60:  # 1 minute
            return dates.SecondLocator(bysecond=range(0,60,20)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorSeconds), \
                   dates.MicrosecondLocator(interval=5000000),dates.DateFormatter('%Ss')
        elif time_delta.seconds < 60*5: # 5 minutes
            return dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,1)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorMinutes), \
                   dates.SecondLocator(bysecond=range(0,60,15)),dates.DateFormatter('%Ss') 
        elif time_delta.seconds < 60*30: # 30 minutes
            return dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,5)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorMinutes), \
                   dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,1)),dates.DateFormatter('%Mm')            
        elif time_delta.seconds < 60*60: # 60 minutes
            return dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,10)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorMinutes), \
                   dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,2)),dates.DateFormatter('%Mm')            
        elif time_delta.seconds < 60*60*10: # 10 hours
            return dates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0,60,1)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorHours), \
                   dates.MinuteLocator(byminute=range(0,60,30)),dates.DateFormatter('%Mm')            
        elif time_delta.seconds < 60*60*24: # 24 hours
            return dates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0,60,3)),dates.ticker.FuncFormatter(formatterMajorHours), \
                   dates.HourLocator(byhour=range(0,60,1)),dates.DateFormatter('%Hh')            

# make up some data
x = np.array([datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(2000)])
y = np.array([i+random.gauss(0,1) for i,_ in enumerate(x)])

# plot
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5), facecolor='white', edgecolor='black')
plt.plot(x,y)

x_axis = plt.gca().get_xaxis()

major_locator,major_formatter,minor_locator,minor_formatter = dynamicDateLocator(x)

x_axis.set_major_locator(major_locator)
x_axis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter)

x_axis.set_minor_locator(minor_locator)
x_axis.set_minor_formatter(minor_formatter)

x_axis.set_tick_params(which='major', labelsize=10)
x_axis.set_tick_params(which='minor', pad=4, labelsize=8, labelcolor='#333333')

plt.grid(which = 'minor', alpha = 0.5)
plt.grid(which = 'major', alpha = 0.9)

plt.show()
```

Comment: What, precisely, do you want us to tell you?

Comment: Hopefully some existing examples of how to use AutoDateFormatter and the custom formatting rules that I see references for elsewhere, but don't understand quite well enough to put it into use.  I provided my example rules I want to use to help put things in perspective.

Comment: I made some serious progress, but need help with cleaning up the solution.  Thanks!

Comment: A lot of code to read! Can you boil down one or two of the things you need to do into a single example that shows what the input is and what you want the output to be, and perhaps, what software you prefer to use to obtain the result?

Comment: Bill, the code works as is now.  I am pretty happy with how it visually looks on the plots.  To see for your self, just change the last number in range() where we make up data for x and y.  I just cant help but think there is a more efficient way of doing this.